# How to write linq-to-entity query with union all and innerjoin on whole query

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, linq-to-entities

I am trying to translate this SQL query into linq-to-entities and I do not know how to translate the "With G As" and the query 2, that is performing an inner join with G:

```
WITH G AS (

    -- DONE
        SELECT  
            rt1.*,
            CAST(rt1.ACCOUNT_ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN AS PARENT_PATH,
            CAST(rt1.NUMBER AS VARCHAR(MAX)) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN AS NUMBER_PATH,
            rt1.NUMBER AS PARENT_NUMBER,
            0 AS DEPTH
        FROM    
            ACCOUNT rt1
        WHERE   
            rt1.PARENT_ID IS NULL 
            AND rt1.ACCOUNT_ID <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
            AND rt1.STATEMENT_ID = '622f1e99-737c-4a77-be72-eacdec32203e'
    -- DONE
    -- in progress
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  
            rt2.*,
            G.PARENT_PATH + '/' + CAST(rt2.ACCOUNT_ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,
            G.NUMBER_PATH + '/' + CAST(rt2.NUMBER AS VARCHAR(MAX)) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,
            G.NUMBER AS PARENT_NUMBER,
            G.DEPTH + 1
        FROM    
            ACCOUNT rt2
            INNER JOIN G
                ON rt2.PARENT_ID = G.ACCOUNT_ID
        WHERE   
            rt2.ACCOUNT_ID <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
            AND rt2.STATEMENT_ID = '622f1e99-737c-4a77-be72-eacdec32203e'
            -- in progress
    )
```

Do you have an idea of a reference explaining how to write proper linq-to-entity queries?

Best,

Nico